# JavaFX and TableView how to retrive data using a LinkedList inside an object

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a class called "Scag" and I want to show all data into a TableView.

```
public class RTS {
private String id;
private double f;
private double d;
private double q;
private double c;
private String tabName; 
private LinkedList<Scag> sc;
[.......]
}
```

In the main function I have a LinkedList and I want to see all data shown in a TableView this way:
    f | d | q | c | tabName | sc[0].a | [sc[0].b | sc[1].a | sc[1].b | etc..
    2nd row..
    3th row..
    etc..

For the firsts parameters i have no problem, but I have no idea how to handle the parameters in the LinkedList

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Suggest that you show the code that you're using for the data that you can get into the list and what you tried (if anything) for the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < listSize ; i++) {
    TableColumn<RTS, String> aCol = new TableColumn<>("sc["+i+"].a");
    final int index = i ;
    aCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
        new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getSc().get(index).getA()));

    TableColumn<RTS, String> bCol = new TableColumn<>("sc["+i+"].b");
    bCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
        new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getSc().get(index).getB()));

    table.getColumns().add(aCol);
    table.getColumns().add(bCol);
}
```

Since you didn't show the `Scag` class I just guessed that `a` and `b` were fields of type `String` with appropriate `get` methods, and that there is a suitable get method for the list itself in `RTS`: you can obviously adjust as needed.